# SQL JOIN - Cant use Alias, can't access the column. Could not be bound/Invalid Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, ssms

I have the following example

```
  SELECT    
        a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS Account, 
        a.Payment AS Collection,
        CONCAT(c.FacilityCode, a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS Client_Account,

FROM    TEMP_TABLE_2 a
LEFT JOIN   denial_table d ON a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER= d.account_number

--Issue here
INNER JOIN  events_table e ON Client_Account = e.fk_Account
--

INNER JOIN  flist_table b ON a.FACILITY_CODE = b.client_facility
INNER JOIN  ref_f_table c ON c.ID = b.fk_facility_id
```

The issue is in the 2nd Join

- I cannot use Alias 'Client_Account'

  - *Invalid column name*
- I cannot use CONCAT(c.FacilityCode, a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER)

  - *Multi-part identifier could not be bound*

How can I access CONCAT(c.FacilityCode, a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) in the 2nd Join??

Using T-SQL

Comment: I would suggest using better aliases than a,b,c. That is just a nightmare to work with. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: you need to know the actual execution order of TSQL instead of logical order

Comment: @SeanLange yeah those aren't the actual Aliases.  Or table names.  I suppose for the question I could have used better ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the full expression (not the alias) *and* put the tables in the correct order:

```
SELECT a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS Account, a.Payment AS Collection,
       CONCAT(c.FacilityCode, a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS Client_Account,
       . . .
FROM TEMP_TABLE_2 a INNER JOIN
     flist_table b
     ON a.FACILITY_CODE = b.client_facility INNER JOIN 
     ref_f_table c
     ON c.ID = b.fk_facility_id INNER JOIN
     events_table e
     ON CONCAT(c.FacilityCode, a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER) = e.fk_Account LEFT JOIN
     denial_table d
     ON a.PATIENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER= d.account_number
```

As a benefit, I think it is better to put the `INNER JOIN`s before the `LEFT JOIN`s.  It helps make sure that a `NULL`-key (from a non-matching row) is not inadvertently used in an `ON` clause.

Comment: Aha, so the Order of the tables do matter.  I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Wish I knew how simple the answer was. Thank you for your help Gordon!